# Mechanism causing red fluorescence from green (532nm) laser in household glass

Tags: laser, glass, laser-interaction, fluorescence

## Background / Experiment

I was surprised by [this](https://mastodon.social/@gigabecquerel@chaos.social/110707048912115684) toot by @gigabecquerel, where the author shows red fluorescence in the thick bottom of a (drink) glass when exposed to a cheap consumer-grade green laser pointer laser. They also [verified](https://mastodon.social/@gigabecquerel@chaos.social/110707673048833531) that it's not some kind of selective scattering or such of a minor red component in the original laser, by using a diffraction grating to definitely select a monochromatic beam.

I was able to reproduce these results (no filtering, though).

[image: Laser cast through, in that order of transmission, the bottom of a whiskey tumbler, which actually used to be a glass candle, the bottom of a white beer glass and the bottom of a tall pilsner glass. The beam path is visible in red!]

[image: Green Laser shone into handle of glass jug; a beam of reddish light is visible following the rest emanating from the coupling point]

I was able to show this red fluorescence for

- Thick-walled drinking glasses
- Thin-walled -"-
- Glass jugs
- Glass bottles

I've not been able to reproduce with heat-resistant glassware (i.e., a glassware casserole dish), but that might be because of all walls being curved and it thus being hard to couple in a beam at the right angle without scattering too much green light, making the red undetectable.

I tried but could not reproduce with saturated sugar water (tested that for the refractive index being closer to that of glass, in hopes I could use its surface to more cleanly couple in beams). I didn't explicitly test water, but it would have struck me, if it flouresced in red, I'd think.

@gigabecquerel [went on](https://mastodon.social/@gigabecquerel@chaos.social/110712218668094579) and showed stronger red fluorescence in organic material – olive oil. That threw all of my "dopants in partially cristalline lattice" theories out the window. That is, of course, assuming it's the same mechanism.

## Question

What is the mechanism by which red light gets emitted by household glass when hit by a 532 nm laser?

Comment: LIF, laser induced fluorescence seems a complicated and useful study https://cefrc.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf1071/files/Files/2011%20Lecture%20Notes/Alden/Lecture-5-LIF.pdf  . Lets hope an expert answers.

Comment: For olive oil, the fluorescence is due to chlorophyll. For cheap glass, the fluorescence can be due to the decolonizing substances added when the glass is made. Using laser pointers makes it relatively easy to see fluorescence in various substances: try beer, gin, whisk(e)y, etc. Using shorter wavelength laser pointers reveals even more fluorescent substances, e.g., quinine in tonic water: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678.

Comment: @EdV now I'll have to research decolonization

Comment: Darn autocorrect! I meant decolorizing and autocorrect tried to get me again. Anyway, inexpensive glass can have the green (iron impurity) tint ‘removed’ by addition of manganese, if I remember correctly.

Comment: aha! Now that's a lead! (as in clue, not as in group 14), @EdV.

Comment: I am going to hazard the guess that manganese ions in the glass are the source of the red fluorescence, sort of like the near IR emission due to neodymium ions in various glass environments: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/158765/79678. So, not far from the “partially crystalline lattice” working hypothesis you had. Hope this is a useful hint.

Comment: Looks like a perfect case of a bounty attracting an excellent answer! Nice when it works!

Comment: @Ankit not really, no. I know what photoluminescence is, I ask about that!

Comment: @EdV Just wish it hadn't been closed :( especially not with s question that asks what luminescence is, ever even my title asks about the specific photoluminescent mechanism involved. Anyway, I got an excellent answer which I'm very happy with!

Comment: I agree this question is more specific than the duplicate and should not have been closed since it requires a different kind of answer; I have reopened it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reddish colour produced by a green laser pointer passing through common glass objects is due to excitation of luminescence centres produced by the particular composition and matrix structure of the glass.

Fluorescence is when light excites a system that then almost immediately emits a lower energy photon.  The system can be an atom, a molecule such a chlorphyll, or a luminescence centre in a crystal lattice or glass matrix.  What typically happens is that a high energy photon excites the system which then quickly transitions non-radiatively (e.g. through vibrational transitions) to a lower energy state which, in turn, radiatively de-excites emitting a photon.

As mentioned by @Ed-V in the comments, the red fluorescence from olive oil is due to chlorophyl.  [Chlorophyll fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_fluorescence) was first reported by [David Brewster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Brewster) in his 1833 article ["On the Colours of Natural Bodies"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=29y7R_REf5EC&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false).  Fresh extra virgin olive has a high chlorophyll content and fluoresces red (680 nm band) under a green laser, but poor quality or degraded olive oil will fluoresce yellow. See, for example: ["Fun with fluorescence in olive oil"](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4745700), ["Deeper Insight into Fluorescence—Excitation of Molecules by Light"](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4801364), or ["Fluorescence Spectra Measurement of Olive Oil and Other Vegetable Oils"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/jaoac/83.6.1435).

Pure soda–lime–silica glasses are not fluorescent, but as also mentioned by @Ed-V, the reddish fluorescence in your glass is likely due to decolourizing agents acting as fluorescent ["activators"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence#Gemology,_mineralogy_and_geology). Decolourizors are traditionally needed because iron (as Fe$_2$O$_3$) is an ubiquitous contaminant that gives a green tint to common glass, and [for centuries manganese oxide has been added](https://www.conciatore.org/2015/08/decolorization-of-glass.html) to glass to decolourize it.   Modern glass may be decolourized by [selenium](https://libanswers.cmog.org/faq/144879) or [cerium](https://www.cmog.org/article/solarized-glass), but I believe the essential physics and chemistry are all similar.

According to [Kreidl](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.35.000249), the fluorescence of manganese-doped glass is due to the transitions of Mn$^{2+}$ ions embedded in the glass matrix.
Mn$^{2+}$ ions do not fluorescence when dissolved in water, but when dissolved in glass they can create luminescence centres that can fluorescence under ultraviolet in colours ranging from green to red depending the composition and structure of the surrounding glass matrix.  Greenish fluorescence occurs when the  Mn$^{2+}$ ions form part of the (mostly) SiO$_2 $ glass network, while red/orange fluorescence occurs when the Mn$^{2+}$ occupy more loosely bound interstitial locations. The exact colour emitted depends on the energy states of the luminescence centre formed by each Mn$^{2+}$ ion interacting with its specific neighbours.

- For more detailed discussion of Mn$^{2+}$ in glass, e.g. which specific transitions may be involved, check out Section 1.4.2 of [Pierre Mênassa's PhD thesis](https://dam-oclc.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/cc394744-bd73-4692-a27b-6a66b7bebb67).

Since manganese is no longer common in modern glass, the actual cations producing the reddish fluorescence are likely not Mn$^{2+}$.
Selenium doped glass fluoresces [pink or orange](https://www.beachcombingmagazine.com/blogs/news/ultraviolet-sea-glass), which I think is also consistent with what you observe (and with my own quick experiment with a green laser pointer and some glass tumblers).
I can't find much information on cerium doped glass luminescence, but the peak of its fluorescence may be in the blue (see [Marczuk](https://opticaapplicata.pwr.edu.pl/article.php?id=1980100079) or [Herrmann et al](https://doi.org/10.1364/OME.5.000720)).

It would be interesting to see what colour fluorescence is produced in your glass by UV radiation. (This might be hard to see, however, with typical consumer UV lamps.)
Do the higher energy UV photons excite other colours?  For example, a contribution from Mn$^{2+}$ (or other cation) green band  might turn the combined fluorescence yellow.

Finally, I would not be surprised if your casserole dish does not visibly fluoresce.  Such cookware may be made of [borosilicate glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borosilicate_glass). I don't know the composition or quality of the glass in your dish, but I do know that high quality borosilicate glass is often used in fluorescent microscopy precisely because of its [very low autofluorescence](https://schott-minifab.com/images/downloads/uncoated/SCHOTT_NX_BF33_General_2014.pdf).

Comment: I already upvoted: this is a comprehensive answer that addresses everything very well!

Comment: Wow, this is nicer than I hoped for! Thank you so much, not only for the excellent text, but also giving sources. Regarding UV: I do have a high-powered UV-C LED at my disposal, if I can find it, but I don't have the protective equipment that would put me at ease while working with it; might have to ask a friend for cooperation on that.