# Does Color change happen under a prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, frequency

I was watching [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/l6VX9NAZVvU)

It Showed that light ( green ) changes its color to red after incidence of light. I couldn't think of how this happens because light's color is dependent on frequency rather than wavelength and only the wavelength changes when light enters a new medium , according to these [answers on whether light is depended on wavelength or frequency.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/what-determines-color-wavelength-or-frequency)

So what explanation can be given for the change in color in a prism.

Comment: The equilateral prism is probably acrylic, so the color is due to impurity fluorescence excited by the cyan color laser light from the laser pointer. I have seen this with various inexpensive equilateral prisms I have, but not with the expensive equilateral prisms in my echelle spectrographs.

Comment: See this as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773245/313612.

Comment: @EdV Oh I did not know that , thank you very much, then it was primarily due to fluorescence

Comment: Yeah. The prism in the video is good for visualization purposes, as in the video or in lecture demonstrations, but it would be poor (or useless) in an actual spectroscopy scenario because the fluorescence would be a parasitic nuisance, as it were.